# Boundary condition and Feller boundary classification (is it possible to have only inacessible boundaries)?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

The following pages are from Ethier and Kurtz (Markov Processes  Characterization and Convergence pages 366-367)

[image]

[image]

[image]

I am interested in the following idea. Assume that $r_1$ and $r_2$ are both inacessible, that is they are both entrance or natural boundary points according to the classification above mentioned. In this case, $\mathcal{D}$ generates a feller semigroup and no further restriction was needed. How do we interpret this in light of the phrase

[image]

This seems to be at odds with the theorem unless there one can't have only inaccessible boundaries.

Therefore my question: is it possible to have only inacessible boundary points?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can hae both boundaries as inaccessible boundaries.
 The point here is to interpret correctly the meaning of restriction (in a broad sense) of G in an appropriate setting, that is, If $D_1 = D_2 = D$ then you restrict $D$ to itself.